# Apache Beam how to filter data based on date value

Tags: java, apache-beam

I am trying to read records from a CSV file and filter the records based on the date. I have implemented this in the following way. But is this a correct way?

The steps are:

1. Creating pipeline
2. Read the data from a file
3. Perform necessary filtering
4. Create a MapElement Object and convert the OrderRequest to String
5. Mapping the OrderRequest Entity to String
6. Write the output to a file

Code:

```
// Creating pipeline
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();

// For transformations Reading from a file
PCollection<String> orderRequest = pipeline
        .apply(TextIO.read().from("src/main/resources/ST/STCheck/OrderRequest.csv"));

PCollection<OrderRequest> pCollectionTransformation = orderRequest
        .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, OrderRequest>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                String rowString = c.element();
                if (!rowString.contains("order_id")) {
                    String[] strArr = rowString.split(",");
                    OrderRequest orderRequest = new OrderRequest();
                    orderRequest.setOrder_id(strArr[0]);
                    // Condition to check if the

                    String source1 = strArr[1];
                    DateTimeFormatter fmt1 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("mm/dd/yyyy");
                    DateTime d1 = fmt1.parseDateTime(source1);
                    System.out.println(d1);

                    String source2 = "4/24/2017";
                    DateTimeFormatter fmt2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("mm/dd/yyyy");
                    DateTime d2 = fmt2.parseDateTime(source2);
                    System.out.println(d2);

                    orderRequest.setOrder_date(strArr[1]);
                    System.out.println(strArr[1]);

                    orderRequest.setAmount(Double.valueOf(strArr[2]));
                    orderRequest.setCounter_id(strArr[3]);
                    if (DateTimeComparator.getInstance().compare(d1, d2) > -1) {
                        c.output(orderRequest);
                    }
                }
            }
        }));

// Create a MapElement Object and convert the OrderRequest to String
MapElements<OrderRequest, String> mapElements = MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
        .via((OrderRequest orderRequestType) -> orderRequestType.getOrder_id() + " "
                + orderRequestType.getOrder_date() + " " + orderRequestType.getAmount() + " "
                + orderRequestType.getCounter_id());

// Mapping the OrderRequest Entity to String
PCollection<String> pStringList = pCollectionTransformation.apply(mapElements);

// Now Writing the elements to a file
pStringList.apply(TextIO.write().to("src/main/resources/ST/STCheck/OrderRequestOut.csv").withNumShards(1)
        .withSuffix(".csv"));

// To run pipeline
pipeline.run();

System.out.println("We are done!!");
```

Pojo Class:

```
public class OrderRequest  implements Serializable{
    String order_id;
    String order_date;
    double amount;
    String counter_id;
}
```

Though I am getting the correct result, is this a correct way? My two main problem is

```
1) How to i access individual columns? So that, I can specify conditions based on that column value.
2) Can we specify headers when reading the data?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can process CSV files like this using `TextIO.read()` provided they do not contain fields embedding newlines and you can recognize/skip the header lines. Your pipeline looks good, though as a minor style issue I would probably have the first ParDo do only the parsing, followed by a Filter that looked at the date to filter things out.

If you want to automatically infer the header lines, you could open read the first line in your main program (using standard java libraries, or Beams [FileSystems](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileSystems.html) class) and extract this out manually, passing it into your parsing DoFn.

I agree a more columnar approach would be more natural. We have this in Python as our [Dataframes API](https://beam.apache.org/blog/dataframe-api-preview-available/) which is now available for [general use](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/CHANGES.md#highlights-1).  You would write something like

```
with beam.Pipeline() as p:
   df = p | beam.dataframe.io.read_csv("src/main/resources/ST/STCheck/OrderRequest.csv")
   filtered = df[df.order_date > limit]
   filtered.write_csv("src/main/resources/ST/STCheck/OrderRequestOut.csv")
```