# Apache Beam exit pipeline on condition Python SDK

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have an Apache Beam pipeline which reads from a BigQuery table and does a few processing. The dataflow job would be triggered by a Cloud Function.
My requirement is to check a date column in the BigQuery which it reads at the first step and stop the pipeline from proceeding to the next stages if the date is same as today.

```
data = (
    pipeline
    | beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(query='''
    SELECT date, unique_key, case_number FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_crime.crime` LIMIT 100
    ''', use_standard_sql=True)
    # Further data processing
)

count = (data 
    | beam.Filter(lambda line : line['date'] == datetime.now())
    | beam.combiners.Count.Globally()
)

# Further data processing
```

The 'data' PCollection is my actual processing.
The solution which I had in mind was creating a PCollection 'count' which checks if the date is same as today. But how can I add a logic to check if the count is greater than 0 and then step exit the pipeline by logging necessary information?

Or is there a better way to do this instead?

Comment: Does this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69438903/apache-beam-how-to-filter-data-based-on-date-value/69441877#69441877) help you?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT This shows how to filter the PCollection. My requirement is to check the count of it and gracefully exit the pipeline and not continue the processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your issue with the following code :

```py
class BadLineException(Exception):
    pass

def line_can_be_processed(self, line) -> bool:
    if line['date'] == datetime.now():
        logging.info("My info about processing if date is now, the line can't be processed")
        raise BadLineException("The line can't be processed !!!", line)
    else:
        return True
        
def test_pipeline(self):
    with TestPipeline() as p:
        data = (
                p
                | beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(query='''
                        SELECT date, unique_key, case_number FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_crime.crime` LIMIT 100
                        ''', use_standard_sql=True)
            # Further data processing
        )
    
        (data
         | beam.Filter(self.line_can_be_processed)
         | beam.Map(self.fake_transform)
         )
```

Some explanations :

- For the `Filter`, I put the logic in a separated method, if the current date is now, I log the needed information and raise a custom Exception, it will stop the pipeline and mark it as failed. Otherwise I return `True`

If you want to have more control on the lines that could not be processed, you can also apply a multi sinks and store them in a file or a `BigQuery` table.

With multi sinks you will have :

```
Sink 1 => Good lines 
Sink 2 => Lines that could not be processed
```

Comment: Thanks for this Mazlum. But my requirement is just to exit the pipeline when the date is today. Not filter on the good lines and bad lines. I might have been not clear with the requirement.

Comment: If at least one line has a date with today, you want to exit the pipeline, without treating the rest of lines ?

Comment: My example treats only the lines with date different from today. The lines with a date equals to today are skipped but logged.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I want to exit the pipeline even if one of the rows has date as today.

Comment: In this case you when a line date is equal is equals to today, you can raise en exception. This will stop and break the pipeline but the job will be marked as failed. If you it corresponds to your need, I can update my answer in this direction.

Comment: Yes please. That would be helpful.

Comment: I edited my answer, with a raise exception if a line can't be processed.